Question about AGPLv3. How to state that I modified source code?
So here is what I want to know.
As one Project's code I added to my own uses AGPLv3 license i licensed my own Project as AGPLv3 but there is such a step as "Conveying Modified Source Versions" in AGPLv3 license.
SO what I should do is to Add license text to UI, add license text to source, and the most important is the "a)" Where should I include such notices and how should the look like?


Conveying Modified Source Versions.

You may convey a work based on the Program, or the modifications to
produce it from the Program, in the form of source code under the
terms of section 4, provided that you also meet all of these conditions:
a) The work must carry prominent notices stating that you modified
it, and giving a relevant date.
b) The work must carry prominent notices stating that it is
released under this License and any conditions added under section
7.  This requirement modifies the requirement in section 4 to
"keep intact all notices".
c) You must license the entire work, as a whole, under this
License to anyone who comes into possession of a copy.  This
License will therefore apply, along with any applicable section 7
additional terms, to the whole of the work, and all its parts,
regardless of how they are packaged.  This License gives no
permission to license the work in any other way, but it does not
invalidate such permission if you have separately received it.
d) If the work has interactive user interfaces, each must display
Appropriate Legal Notices; however, if the Program has interactive
interfaces that do not display Appropriate Legal Notices, your
work need not make them do so.

Is this enough(There are links to github pages under project names in .md file so they are not displayed here):
Name's code is modified from Name's project's branch v2.1.7 ProjectName, which is licensed under AGPLv3 license. To meet AGPLv3 license obligations, I have licensed MyProjectName under AGPLv3 license. To meed AGPLv3 license obligations, I declare that i have modified source code taken from ProjectName and included modified source code in MyProjectName, both modification and inclusion were made on May 9, 2024.
